# Is @JsName annotation required for every method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, kotlin, actions-on-google, kotlin-js-interop

I was trying to make NodeJs work with Kotlin for a HelloWorld example [here](https://github.com/PravSonawane/hello-actions-nodejs-apiai-kotlin).

As per the [Kotlin JS documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/js-to-kotlin-interop.html#jsname-annotation), @JsName annotation is required for **overloaded** methods. But in my experience, it is required even for a **single** method. Without this annotation the compiler adds a suffix to the method name as shown in the screenshot.[image]

Is this a bug? Or am I missing something?

I'm using Kotlin 1.1.0 module provided by NPM (please check the GitHub link above for the complete codebase if required).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kotlin compiler mangles names all functions, except for those which don't take any parameters. The motivation is: you can add overloaded function later, and this should not break binary compatibility of the code. As for `@JsName`: it depends on your goal. I don't know it and hence I can't tell whether you shuold put `@JsName` annotation on each method. If you are developing a library which is intended to be used from JavaScript, yes, you probably need to put `@JsName` on each function you want to be accessible from JavaScript. We are going to add another annotation which  turns off mangling on entire class or file.

Comment: Thanks. I think it would be helpful if you can add 'Kotlin compiler mangles names all functions, except for those which don't take any parameters.' to the documentation.